# how to prove that the convolution between two discrete signals is the discrete signal of convolution between two continuous signals

Tags: discrete-signals, convolution, continuous-signals

Like the title. We already know $x[n]$ and $h[n]$ are the discrete time signal of $x(t)$ and $h(t)$ respectively, which are continuous time signals. And also $x(t)*h(t)=y(t)$, $x[n]*h[n]=y[n]$. Prove that $y[n]$ is the discrete time signal of $y(t)$.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?  Have you considered working out the continuous convolution, sampling it and comparing it to the discrete case?

Comment: Let $x(t) = \delta(t - T_s / 2)$, where $T_s$ is the sampling interval.  Let $h(t) = u(t) a e^{-a t}$.  Then $y(t) = u(t - T_s / 2) a^{a T_s/2} e^{-a t}$.  Now observe that $x[n] = 0 \forall n$, and that if you convolve it with _anything_ the result will be zero.  Thus, $y[n] = 0$ and -- oh crap.  Did the prof put any _constraints_ on $x(t)$ and $h(t)$?

Comment: What is your reason for believing that the result that you are asked to prove is true? It might be easier to come up with a counterexample to the alleged result.

Comment: Then what should be the case if the above statement isn't true? Is it not true only under certain circumstances?

Comment: @jsnjztr didn't you read my comment?  I disprove the hypothesis that $y[n]$ is the discrete equivalent of $y(t)$ in every case, by _showing you a case_ where that is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Say continuous signals $x(t)$, $h(t)$, $y(t)$, sampled continuous signals $x_s(t)$, $h_s(t)$ satisfy

$$
y(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau \tag{1}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
x_s(t) = 
\begin{cases}
      x(t) & t=nT\\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}       
\end{aligned}\tag{2}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
h_s(t) = 
\begin{cases}
      h(t) & t=nT\\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}       
\end{aligned}\tag{3}
$$

where $T$ is the sampling period. The continuous-time convolution of $x_s(t)$ and $h_s(t)$ is given by
$$
\hat{y}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x_s(\tau)h_s(t-\tau)d\tau \tag{4}
$$

Now we have discrete signals $x[n]$, $h[n]$ are the discrete version of sampled continuous signals $x_s(t)$ and $h_s(t)$. $y[n]$ is the discrete convolution of $x[n]$ and $h[n]$
$$
y[n] = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} x[m] h[n-m] \tag{5}
$$

If you are talking about continuous-time convolution between two sampled continuous signals, which is $\hat{y}(t)$, equals to the discrete-time convolution between two discrete signals, which is sampled $y[n]$, that's true because $x_s(t)$ and $h_s(t)$ are zero unless $t=nT$ and the integral in Eq. (4) is reduced to summation.

But $y(t)$ is a full integral whose discrete signal is not equal to $\hat{y}(t)$ nor $y[n]$. These two pictures are going to help you understand.

Eq. (1): $$y(t_0) = \int_{\tau=0}^5 x(\tau)h(t_0-\tau) d\tau$$

[image]

Eq. (4) and Eq. (5): $$y[n_0] = \sum_{m=0}^5 x[m]h[n_0-m]$$

[image]

I think [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/81504/why-the-convolution-of-the-impulse-response-doesnt-match-the-systems-output) is related.