# Why doesn't the convolution of the impulse response match the system's output?

Tags: python, linear-systems, control-systems, scipy

If you define an [LTI system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_time-invariant_system) `sys` in `scipy`, you may conveniently feed an input `x` to it to get its output `y` as follows:

```py
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# let's define as mass-damper-spring system:
# x'' + beta x' + w0**2 x = F/m
m = 10
w0 = 20*2*np.pi
beta = 1.5 

fs = 500 # sampling frequency (Hz)
ts = np.arange(0,100,1./fs) # time interval of simulation
sys = signal.lti(1./m,[1,beta, w0**2]) 

# simulate the response to an input
x = 10+np.random.normal(0,1,size=ts.shape) # input
_, y, _ = sys.output(U = x, T=ts, ) # output
```

However, it is also possible convolve the impulse response (which is also accessible via `lti` module) with the input and find the output to the input:

```py
_, kern = sys.impulse(T=ts) # impulse response 
y_conv = signal.convolve(kern/fs,x)[:len(ts)] #1/fs=dt of integration
```

I realized that the normalized `y_conv` and normalized `y` differ even though they should be the same theoretically (look below):

```
fig, axs= plt.subplots(3,1, figsize=(10,5), sharex=True)
axs[0].plot(ts, y,label='output y') 
axs[1].scatter(ts, y-y_conv,marker='.', label='difference') 
axs[2].plot(ts, kern, label='kernel (impulse response)') 
plt.xlabel('time')
for ax in axs:
    ax.legend()
```

[image]

Indeed, scipy team [didn't implement the output of the linear system using convolution](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/ff1d1555fc67589bf94c272a09ca519ae895d63a/scipy/signal/_ltisys.py#L3504).

I did a similar experiment with an even simpler system (`sys = signal.lti(1,[1,1])`) and realized that this error is indeed a function of the sampling frequency `fs`, as the following images indicate (note the ranges of middle panels). The higher the `fs` the lower the difference.

[image]
[image]

These pictures suggest that the difference vanishes asymptotically, as also commented below. However, my questions that concern finite sampling rate regimes are:

1. **How does the sampling frequency cause such differences mathematically? Is there any expression for the error bound?**
2. **What is the role of bilinear mapping in this difference? Is it possible to tailor this mapping to mitigate such numerical discrepancy?**
3. **Which method is more accurate to estimate the response to a general input, and why (implementation-wise)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I investigated this further and turned out the main issue is not really the sampling rate, but the integration approximation. In the code above, I approximated the convolution $kern(t) * x(t)$ with the `sum(kappa * u) *dt`, corresponding to [left Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Right_Riemann_sum) of the integral. A better way to approximate is the trapezoidal rule which can be implemented by `sum(kappa * u) /2 *dt`. As the code below shows, this one matches the response of Scipy's `impulse` much better:

```py
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# let's define as mass-damper-spring system:
# x'' + beta x' + w0**2 x = F/m
m = 10
w0 = 10*2*np.pi
beta = 15 

fs = 2000 # sampling frequency (Hz)
T = 2
ts = t = np.linspace(0, T, int(T*fs), endpoint=False) # time interval of simulation
sys = signal.lti(1./m,[1,beta, w0**2]) 
_, kern = sys.impulse(T=ts) # impulse response 

# Generate an input: I substituted the previous input with a noise-free 
# impulse-like input for a better comparison
# x = 10 + np.random.normal(0, 1, size=ts.shape) # old input
x = np.zeros_like(ts)
x[0] = 1.

_, y, _ = sys.output(U=x, T=ts, ) # output
y_conv_rec = signal.convolve(x, kern)[:len(ts)] * 1./fs     # rectangular elements
y_conv_trap= signal.convolve(x, kern)[:len(ts)] * 1./fs / 2 # trapezoidal rule


fig, axs= plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(8,5), sharex=True)
axs[0].plot(ts, y, label='y (LTI output)', linewidth=2) 
axs[0].plot(ts, y_conv_rec, '--', label='left Riemann sum',)
axs[0].plot(ts, y_conv_trap, ':', label='trapezoidal',)

axs[1].plot(ts, y-y_conv_rec, label='diff left sum')
axs[1].plot(ts, y-y_conv_trap, label='diff trap')

axs[0].set_ylabel('Response')
axs[1].set_ylabel('diff (relateive to LTI output)')
plt.xlabel('time')
for ax in axs:
    ax.legend()
```

[image]

Clearly, the trapezoidal rule isn't the perfect scheme and Scipy uses a more elaborate one. Yet, it's good enough to show that the discrepancy I observed above was indeed due to integration and not, e.g. the kernel estimation.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for adding the update.

Answer (score 2):

> How does the sampling frequency cause such differences?

The differences are caused by the fact that the **discrete-time convolution between two discrete signals** is not equal to **the discrete signal of continuous-convolution between two continuous signals**.

`signal.convolve` gives you the discrete-time convolution result, which refers to convolution sum, while `sys.output` returns the continuous-time convolution result, which is also known as convolution integral.

Although we can't implement a convolution integral using computer, the documentation of [scipy.signal.lsim](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lsim.html#scipy.signal.lsim) indicates that it interpolates the input signal first, and then apply a convolution sum to simulate the output of a continuous-time linear system.

> Which method is more accurate to estimate the response to a general input, and why (implementation-wise)?

Since you are simulating a mass-damper-spring system which is a continuous-time system, `sys.output` is more accurate.

Comment: Thanks @ZR Good hint. Still, it doesn't give me a mechanistic understanding of, for instance, why doubling the `fs` halves the error (or questions of a similar kind). Would you please illustrate it a bit more (or share some links here)?

Comment: @arash This is quite straight forward, the higher the sampling rate, the less difference between discrete signal and continuous signal, and the more convolution sum approximates convolution integral.

Comment: When $f_s\to\infty$ the difference will be gone.

Comment: Sure! The asymptotic behavior is clear. But, please look at my updated set of questions.